# SQL ORACLE error in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a trigger and I get the following error:

> Error(24,5): PLS-00103: Found the symbol "BEGIN" when it was expected one of the following: * & - + / at loop mod remainder rem  and or ||    multiset. I'm quite a newbie, thanks in advance!

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER ins_livro
      instead OF INSERT ON viewLivros
      FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
    cnt NUMBER := 10;
    biggestID Number;
    BEGIN 
        Select max(exemplar_id) into biggestID from exemplar;
        INSERT INTO livro (
                      id_livro, 
                      nome_livro,
                      id_editora,
                      ano,
                      Preco_Aluguer,
                      Preco_Compra,
                      Preco_Multa
                    ) 
        VALUES      (:new.id_livro, 
                     :new.nome_livro, 
                     :new.id_editora, 
                     :new.ano, 
                     :new.Preco_Aluguer, 
                     :new.Preco_Compra, 
                     :new.Preco_Multa 
                    ); 
        WHILE cnt > 0
        BEGIN
          SET biggestID = biggestID + 1
          INSERT INTO exemplar (
                      id_exemplar,
                      id_livro
                      )
          VALUES      (
                      :new.biggestID,
                      :new.id_livro
                      );
          SET cnt = cnt - 1
        END;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your syntax.  Here it is corrected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_livro INSTEAD OF
  INSERT ON viewLivros FOR EACH ROW DECLARE cnt NUMBER := 10;
  biggestID NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(exemplar_id) INTO biggestID FROM exemplar;
    INSERT
    INTO livro
      (
        id_livro,
        nome_livro,
        id_editora,
        ano,
        Preco_Aluguer,
        Preco_Compra,
        Preco_Multa
      )
      VALUES
      (
        :new.id_livro,
        :new.nome_livro,
        :new.id_editora,
        :new.ano,
        :new.Preco_Aluguer,
        :new.Preco_Compra,
        :new.Preco_Multa
      );
    WHILE cnt > 0
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        biggestID := biggestID + 1;
        INSERT
        INTO exemplar
          (
            id_exemplar,
            id_livro
          )
          VALUES
          (
            biggestID,
            :new.id_livro
          );
        cnt := cnt - 1;
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

**Issues:**

You can't use this syntax: `SET biggestID = biggestID + 1`

You need to use: `biggestID := biggestID + 1;`

Notice the `SET` keyword has been removed, `=` has been changed to `:=` and the line has been terminated with a semicolon.

Also, there's no such thing as `:new.biggestID`.  That is a variable that you've defined in the trigger.  It needed to be replaced by just `biggestID`.

Finally, the `BEGIN` and `END` around this block were replaced with `LOOP` and `END LOOP`:

```
 SET biggestID = biggestID + 1
      INSERT INTO exemplar (
                  id_exemplar,
                  id_livro
                  )
      VALUES      (
                  :new.biggestID,
                  :new.id_livro
                  );
      SET cnt = cnt - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `loop` and `end loop` clauses:

```
WHILE cnt > 0
LOOP
BEGIN
      SET biggestID = biggestID + 1
      INSERT INTO exemplar (
                  id_exemplar,
                  id_livro
                  )
      VALUES      (
                  :new.biggestID,
                  :new.id_livro
                  );
      SET cnt = cnt - 1
    END;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: The begin/end aren't really adding anything here anyway, of course. Without an exception clause an inner block seems a bit pointless.